# Row sieving statistics during WHERE clauses combined by AND

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

The website stores information about all specifications of large amount of items and provides user ability to search through the data by adding some filtering conditions at the front-end. At back-end all the conditions are being translated into clauses and joined by `AND` operand.

My aim is to give the user an idea how many goods are being thrown away or left after each filter. Exact numbers aren't very important for the initial sieving (some fuzzy or approximations are fine, because the whole amount is quite large), but at latter stages, when there's ten or so items left, the user should get the proper amount.

There's obvious straightforward way of making as much `SELECT COUNT` queries as he has filters, but I feel that it might be some technique to archive it in more elegant way and without abusing DB much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this with varying levels of difficulty and performance.

The first and most obvious way to me is to simply do a count on the filters which performs fairly well and is not that difficult to implement. An alternative but similar approach would be to group by the values and do a count.

Here's a fiddle as an example of both methods: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0cdcb/26

```
select
    count(product.id) total,
    sum((v0.value = 'spam')::int) v0_is_spam,
    sum((v0.value != 'spam')::int) v0_not_spam,
    sum((v1.value = 'spam')::int) v1_is_spam,
    sum((v1.value != 'spam')::int) v1_not_spam
from product
left join specification_value v0 on v0.product_id = product.id and v0.specification_id = 1
left join specification_value v1 on v1.product_id = product.id and v1.specification_id = 2;

select specification.id, value, count(*)
from specification
left join specification_value on specification.id = specification_value.specification_id
group by specification.id, value;
```

A slightly more difficult way to do something like that is using window functions, a lot more flexible but not as easy to grasp. Docs are here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html

Example query and results:

```
SELECT depname, empno, salary, avg(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname) FROM empsalary;
  depname  | empno | salary |          avg          
-----------+-------+--------+-----------------------
 develop   |    11 |   5200 | 5020.0000000000000000
 develop   |     7 |   4200 | 5020.0000000000000000
 develop   |     9 |   4500 | 5020.0000000000000000
 develop   |     8 |   6000 | 5020.0000000000000000
 develop   |    10 |   5200 | 5020.0000000000000000
 personnel |     5 |   3500 | 3700.0000000000000000
 personnel |     2 |   3900 | 3700.0000000000000000
 sales     |     3 |   4800 | 4866.6666666666666667
 sales     |     1 |   5000 | 4866.6666666666666667
 sales     |     4 |   4800 | 4866.6666666666666667
(10 rows)
```

And lastly, by far the fastest but also most inaccurate and difficult to implement. Using the database statistics to guess the amount of rows. I would not opt for this unless you have millions of rows within a filter set and have no way to reducing it further. Also, don't do this unless the performance is really so bad that it's needed.

Comment: I feel that window function could be the solution, but my concerns is mostly about the performance and redundant queries. For instance, say we got DB of phone specifications. And after user set cpu: arm, ram>2Gb, waterproof and NFC, he should get the numbers like - after first (cpu) filter 1000 phones, after ram - 250, after waterproof - 10 and after NFC - 2 models in database. So, all methods (except the last one), if I'm not mistaken, would require 4 quite similar queries. Initially, I was even thinking about getting information from Query Planner by parsing the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Do note that it might make everything a lot harder than a simple query :) Just look at the updated version, you can get everything in a single query (except the actual results that is).